# Conflict between php and django with apache sites-available

Tags: php, django, apache, vps

I have a vps ubuntu 16, in which I have a web page in Wordpress and one in Django, I decided to update my server using the following command:
 
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

After the update the website in Django stopped working and presents the following message:

Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at support@javiercb.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
Apache / 2.4.37 (Ubuntu) Server at phraster.com Port 80

And in the log file it presents the following message:

[Tue Jan 29 22: 41: 55.852599 2019] [wsgi: error] [pid 11606] [client 181.199.43.182:53977] Truncated or oversized response headers received from daemon process 'phraster': /var/www/phraster/javiercb/apache.conf/web.wsgi, referer: http://phraster.com/

I attach the two files of apache.conf

Due to this problem I bought another vps and unfortunately the probleme you got.

```
#Apache
<virtualhost *:80>
    ServerName phraster.com
    ServerAlias www.phraster.com
    serverAdmin soporte@javiercb.com

    ServerSignature On

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/phraster.com_error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/phraster.com_access.log combined

    DocumentRoot /var/www/phraster/javiercb
    <Directory /var/www/phraster/javiercb>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
    WSGIDaemonProcess phraster python-path=/var/www/phraster/javiercb:/var/www/virtualenv/env_1.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup phraster

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/phraster/javiercb/apache.conf/web.wsgi

    <Directory /var/www/phraster/javiercb/apache.conf>
            <Files web.wsgi.py>
                    Order deny,allow
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/phraster/javiercb/media>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/phraster/javiercb/static>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
    Alias /static/ "/var/www/phraster/javiercb/static/"
    Alias /media/ "/var/www/phraster/javiercb/media/"

    <Directory "/var/www/virtualenv/env_1.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin">
         Order allow,deny
         Options Indexes
         Allow from all
         IndexOptions FancyIndexing
    </Directory>
</virtualhost>
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/phraster/javiercb:/var/www/virtualenv/env_1.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet


#web.wsgi

import os
import sys

path = '/var/www/phraster/javiercb/javiercb'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'javiercb.settings'

# Uncomment the lines below depending on your Django version
# then, for django >=1.5:
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Please someone to give me an idea or to have solved this problem. I thank you for your help.

Greetings Javier.